# How to redirect to a specific index of tabar in swiftUI from content view

Tags: ios, swiftui

This is my tabbar view. I want to call the second Tabbar index from content view when getting some notification. Please help me with the code how to go to the 2nd tab from content view. How to redirect to a specific index of tabar in swiftUI from content view.

```
 struct TabBarUIView: View {
        
        @State var selection = 1
        @State var isTabViewShown = true
        @State var tabSelection: Tabs = .tab1
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
        @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
        init() {
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
        
        
        var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $tabSelection){
                NavigationView{ //if you write the NavigationView here, you cannot remove TabBar after navigation
                    HomeCheckInUIView()
    
                }                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                
                    .tabItem {
                        Image( tabSelection == Tabs.tab1 ? "HomeActive" : "HomeDeactive") //<-- Here
    //Text("Home")
                    }
                    .tag(Tabs.tab1)
                
                NavigationView{ //if you write the NavigationView here, you cannot remove TabBar after navigation
                    SentReceivedUIView()
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image( tabSelection == Tabs.tab2 ? "ice-active" : "ice-deactive") //<-- Here
    
                }
                .tag(Tabs.tab2)
    
                
                NavigationView{//Tab2 also has a NavigationView
                    Text("view 2")
    //                AcceptedListUIView(vm: IBViewModel.userListMap)
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image( tabSelection == Tabs.tab3 ? "MsgActive" : "MsgDeactive") //<-- Here
    
                }
                .tag(Tabs.tab3)
                
                NavigationView{ //if you write the NavigationView here, you cannot remove TabBar after navigation
                    ProfileUIView()
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image( tabSelection == Tabs.tab4 ? "profile-active" : "profile-deactive") //<-- Here
    
                }
                .tag(Tabs.tab4)
                
            }
        }
        enum Tabs{
            case tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4
        }
    }
    struct TabBarUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            TabBarUIView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You just need to pass ```tabSelection``` as a ```Binding``` to the content view. Then the content view can set a new selection.

Comment: [Give enumeration types singular rather than plural names, so that they read as self-evident](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/enumerations/)

Comment: @BenzyNeez can you pls share some example it will be very helpful..I am beginner in swiftui, so getting confused how to implement..

Comment: Np, answer added.

Comment: @BenzyNeez thank you so much for sharing this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on my suggestion in the comments and in response to your request, here is how you can solve it using a `Binding`.

1. Move the enum `Tabs` outside of `TabBarUIView`, so that other views can see it too.

```swift
enum Tabs{
    case tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4
}
```

2. In your content views, add a `Binding` to the state variable that controls the tab selection. For example, here is a dummy implementation of `HomeCheckInUIView`:

```swift
struct HomeCheckInUIView: View {
    @Binding var tabSelection: Tabs

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("HomeCheckInUIView")

            Button("Go to SentReceivedUIView") {
                tabSelection = .tab2
            }
            Button("Go to ProfileUIView") {
                tabSelection = .tab4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Pass the state variable `tabSelection` from `TabBarUIView` to the content views as a binding, for example:

```swift
HomeCheckInUIView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
```

That's it. The content views can now update the tab selection by setting a new value on the binding, as is being done in the dummy implementation of `HomeCheckInUIView` above. This causes a change of tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ObservableObject` that has an `@Published` property of type `Tabs` and then inject it into the environment inside `ContentView`:

```
class TabViewManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab: Tabs = .tab1
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var tabViewManager = TabViewManager()

    var body: some View {
       SomeView
        .environmentObject(tabViewManager)
    }
}
```

You can modify and access it anywhere inside the view hierarchy:

```
@EnvironmentObject var tabViewManager: TabViewManager

var body: some View {
   TabView(selection: $tabViewManager.selectedTab){}
}
```